# In Backbone.js, how come sometimes it gets "disconnected" from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

If I click really fast on some elements, Backbone.js will stop working.  That is...all the AJAX will stop working.

When I change routes and load new things, nothing loads because AJAX bugs out.  I have to refresh the page and click slowly to make it work again.

Also, this happens only when I'm clicking fast on actions that are somewhat heavy.

How can I "reconnect" the app?

**Edit**: I think my server hangs if I click too fast. Because after I click too fast, I wait, and my server's console will start printing the request after a while.

**Edit 2: I don't even have to click fast. After a few clicks (slowly), it just hangs.**

Comment: This shouldn't happen. What do the actions your clicking do?

Comment: Everytime I click, it does a  model.save and then collections.fetch(), followed by re-rendering the view.  If I click really fast, this breaks.  I tried debugging it, and everything seems to work except for the AJAX part.  If I refresh the page (the entire app), then it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

My server didn't return a response for the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a server-side latency problem: your server cannot accept several requests at once because it is overloaded. So you should investigate about your server's performance. However, you have to anticipate this kind of problems in your client scripts. That is, you should inform the user about loadings, allow him to stop it, and disallow him to send too many simultaneous requests.